# Zed Shaw exercise 20 doesn't work

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, for-loop, printing

When I type this below:

```
from sys import argv

script, input_file = argv

def print_all(f):
    print f.read()

def rewind(f):
    f.seek(0)

def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print line_count, f.readline()

    current_file = open(input_file)

    print "First let's print the whole file:\n"

    print_all(current_file)

    print "Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape."

    rewind (current_file)

    print "Let's print three lines:"

    current_line = 1
    print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

    current_line = current_line + 1
    print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

    current_line = current_line + 1
    print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

It doesn't print in my powershell or work it should print this:

```
First let’s print the whole file:
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
Now let’s rewind, kind of like a tape.
Let’s print three lines:
1 This is line 1
2 This is line 2
3 This is line 3
```

in powershell type this: `$ python ex20.py test.txt`

Comment: @jonrsharpe: looks like you indented too much; the `print_a_line` function isn't that long.

Comment: @MartijnPieters reviewing the OP's initial question, I think that's *exactly their problem*; if the lines after the function were correctly indented, the function would certainly get called.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: bingo. And an excuse to see if rolling back gives a secret hat..

Comment: Please re-read [Rule 2](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/intro.html) - **"Type in each sample *exactly*."**. Indentation is important in Python...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not *calling anything*. Your script defines functions but never actually uses any of them.

That's because all the lines that are supposed to call the functions are indented to be part of the `print_a_line()` function. Un-indent those to move them to the module level so that they are executed when the script is run:

```
def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print line_count, f.readline()

current_file = open(input_file)

print "First let's print the whole file:\n"

print_all(current_file)

print "Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape."

rewind (current_file)

print "Let's print three lines:"

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

Comment: It's working except that the print results are not displayed as Zed Shaw suggested:First let’s print the whole file:
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
Now let’s rewind, kind of like a tape.
Let’s print three lines:
1 This is line 1
2 This is line 2
3 This is line 3 I get:                                     First let’s print the whole file:
Now let’s rewind, kind of like a tape.
Let’s print three lines:
1
2
3

Comment: @JossverKraan: sounds like your file is empty.

Comment: It's working now ;-) (does not know how to accept your answer)

Comment: @JossverKraan: there is an outline of a big *V* underneath the post score on my answer. Click on that and it'll turn green, marking the answer as accepted.